# Link only materials

Tags: materials, linked-data, append

Is it possible to link from another file only the materials, but not the rest,
or append an object, but with link with only to the materials?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Link the object, then make it local, the datablock and materials will still be linked.

Comment: I tried and is not working with bones and a complete character

Comment: Well then edit your question and detail your exact steps and expected result. Illustrating it with well-cropped screenshots would help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do this, if you are looking for *just* the materials, not the objects. Go to the *link* or the *append* tab like you would when linking a normal object, then go to your .blend file you want to link from and select *materials* instead of objects that you want to link from the scene. Now it should show up in your materials tab, unless you are in a different renderer than the material is supposed to render in. This should work.